# Not able to get Request-scoped attribute in Action through XMLHttpRequest

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2, http-headers, xmlhttprequest

I am setting receiverid in jsp page. I am sending textarea value in action using ajax
and on same method I am getting client Ip that is working properly.
I also want to get receiverid which is set in jsp page.
But this is showing `NullPointerException`.

In jsp

```xml
<s:set var="receiverid" value="1" scope="request"/>
<form action="" id="post_message_form">
 <s:textarea name="message"></s:textarea>
 <button type="submit" id="submit_status_button">Submit</button>
</form>


 $(document).on('submit', '#post_message_form', function(f) {
        f.preventDefault();
        var formData = $("#post_message_form").serialize();
        console.log(formData);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'PostIt',
            data: formData,
            dataType: "text html",
            success: function(data) {

            }
        })
    });
```

In action

```java
public class UserMessageInsert extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<PostMessages> {
    PostMessages pm = new PostMessages();
    private long aid;
    public String insert() {
             HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
            String ipAdd = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
            if (ipAdd == null) {
                ipAdd = request.getRemoteAddr();
                long l=(Long) request.getAttribute("receiverid");//NulllPointer Exception
                System.out.println("Ip is "+ipAdd+" l is "+getAid());
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is that the AJAX call is ignoring your request-scoped attributes, since it creates a brand new XMLHttpRequest instead of a classic HttpRequest.

Just add your attribute as hidden parameter in the form, unless you have reasons not to do so:

```xml
<s:set var="receiverid" value="1" scope="request"/>
<form action="" id="post_message_form">

    <s:hidden value="%{#request.receiverid}" name="receiverid" />

    <s:textarea name="message"></s:textarea>
    <button type="submit" id="submit_status_button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then it will get serialized and submitted, and you will access it with a setter, or with `getParameter()`, instead of `getAttribute()`.

Comment: Yes I am doing the same thing. But I am unable to get receiverid  value from request scope .

Comment: Because you are using AJAX I guess

Comment: but Ip daddess is printed properly from request scope

Comment: That is a header, not an attribute.

Comment: Have you investigated any further, do you still have doubts... ?

Comment: NO I didnt find any way for this. But I think there should be any way to pass with ajax

Comment: What's wrong with using an hidden parameter that is then serialized in the request ? Why a request-scoped attribute is better than a request parameter here ?

Comment: I dont have Idea about that. I want parameter should not be visible to user not even by inspecting in firfox or chrome

Comment: Ok, then here we go with the *real* question. Since you know the value you are defining (either if you create it in the page, like in the example, or if you get it from the Action), then why putting it in the page at all ? Put it in the session in the Action, then render the JSP page, then when you perform the AJAX call, retrieve it from the session in the AJAX Action, eventually cleaning it. Sounds fine ?

Comment: I put in session scope like id=23 before showing page this is ok . But problem is when we open more than 1 page for this new id value over rides old one and I got data for both in new id.

Comment: Ok, this seems like another, interesting question, and hence should be asked as a new one. This question instead is the perfect case of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/214186): your problem is that you can't preserve the uniqueness of your IDs in session across multiple calls and pages, then you've tried using request-scoped attribute, receiving NPE, and finally you asked about *your solution* instead than about *your real problem*. Please consider accepting/upvoting the answer since THIS question (why id is null with request-scoped attributes and AJAX ?) is answered...